# Which is the first reference using the terminology "Chinese Remainder Theorem" for this theorem?

Tags: mathematics, terminology, number-theory

The *Chinese Remainder Theorem* is one of the fundamental theorems in modular arithmetic. As far as I know, this terminology for the theorem is due to the fact that the Chinese mathematicians were the first in developing it (as suggested by remaining works of the 3rd century of Sun Zia and the book *Mathematical Treatise in Nine Sections* of 1247 of Qin Jiushao).

In parallel, the theorem was rediscovered by western mathematicians in the modern age. As far as I read, Gauss doesn't refer to it as the Chinese Remainder Theorem in his *Disquisitiones Arithmeticae*, so I am curious about when this terminology became commonplace in mathematics as it is today. Hence the questions are:

- Which is the first reference using the terminology "Chinese Remainder Theorem" for this theorem?
- At which point can we consider that this was the common place terminology of this theorem?

Comment: A posting on the math overflow site gives a lot of information on this topic.  Please see : http://mathoverflow.net/questions/11951/what-is-the-history-of-the-name-chinese-remainder-theorem